# Flaky Lenovo docking station with Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, lenovo-laptop, charging, docking-station

I experience flaky connectivity with my Lenovo T490s and the USB-C docking station.

Symptoms:
- External monitor drops out
- Charging laptop battery requires reconnecting the USBC cable multiple times (or doesn't work at all).
- Peripherals (mouse, keyboard, monitor) sometimes have to be connected directly to the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Lenovo BIOS/UEFI firmware seems to have fixed these issues.

Downloaded the updates and followed the instructions [provided by Lenovo](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/uu/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t490s-type-20nx-20ny/downloads/driver-list/)

I used the route with the `fwupdmgr` tool to upgrade which worked fine.